# looping through file to add to datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, for-loop, datagridview

I'm trying to display data in a table in a windows form. I don't yet know how to use databases, so I'm trying to use a file read into an array to populate DataGridView. 
When I run the program, the data starts in the second column, instead of the first. And the same data is repeated in each row.

I'm open to doing this in a different way, but I've had trouble understanding many of the other methods that I've come across. I'm a beginner so I need a simple solution or a very detailed explanation so that I actually understand what the code is doing.

```
  private void buttonAllOrders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // call method to read file
        string[] allLines = ReadFile();
        // add columns
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("DateColumn", "Date");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("LemonColumn", "Lemon");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("TrefoilColumn", "Trefoils");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("DSDColumn", "Do-Si-Dos");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("SamoasColumn", "Samoas");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("TagsColumn", "Tagalongs");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ThinMintsColumn", "Thin Mints");

        // loop through array to populate each row
        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(allLines[0], allLines[1], allLines[2], allLines[3], allLines[4],
                allLines[5], allLines[6], allLines[7] );
        }
```

Comment: How is the file look like?

Comment: The same data is repeated because you reference the same elements in the array on each iteration. You never use i in the loop.

Comment: Read the data into a collection and use the collection as a datasource is the easiest way.

Comment: After the variable `string[] allLines` gets its data ... what does `allLines[0]` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is currently creating a new row only using the first 8 elements of your 'allLines' array.

You probably want to do something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i += 8)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(allLines[i], allLines[i + 1], allLines[i + 2], 
    allLines[i + 3], allLines[i + 4], allLines[i + 5], allLines[i + 6], allLines[i + 7]);
}
```

Here have I changed the increment from `i++` to `i += 8` and added that index to the array call this way each time the loop runs it will get the next 8 items. This should solve your issue of having the same data in every row.

Since I do not know what is in your file I cannot tell you why the information starts in the second column.

Comment: Thanks, Reed. Your explanation helped me understand what was going on. And now it starts in the first column

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as Reed only a bit less typing and I think Reed will be out of columns. Your code shows 7 columns.

```
private void OPCode()
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("DateColumn", "Date");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("LemonColumn", "Lemon");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("TrefoilColumn", "Trefoils");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("DSDColumn", "Do-Si-Dos");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("SamoasColumn", "Samoas");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("TagsColumn", "Tagalongs");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ThinMintsColumn", "Thin Mints");

        string[] alllines = File.ReadAllLines("Path to file");
        //Create an array to hold values for the row
        string[] row = new string[7];
        //loop through all the lines in the file but step by 7
        //because we will use the lines inbetween to populate each row
        for (int i = 0; i < alllines.Count(); i += 7)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            {
                row[x] = alllines[x + i];
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JohnG I did test this code but I guess the file I used came out even. Only tested on a single file. I will check some more and fix the code. Thank you.

Comment: The code crashes for me... The OP is missing what the variable `allLines` "contains". I am guessing a CSV string. Adding an `if (x + i < alllines.Count()) { ...` to the code should prevent it from crashing however, IMHO the code is not doing what the OP wants. The OP needs to clarify what is in each string.

Comment: Thank you. This code did work in my program and your comments in the code were helpful to me.

Comment: @Dani I am glad your code is working but take note of JohnG 's comment if your text file has an extra line, my code will not work.

Comment: John, it actually was doing what I wanted it to do -  each string contains the date and the quantity of each flavor. I wanted to print the date and each quantity in the corresponding column.